# Fragment code in main activity does not fill the whole screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i have problem with my FragmentLayout in main class. i have app for location, in my main activity is map (google API) and i have a menu, FragmentLayout (in my main activity XML) is wrap_content (height), when i click on Settings, FragmentLayout is shows but its not cover the whole screen just a part and under settings i see map (which not should be there). When i set up match_parent for my FragmentLaout then i dont see the map in from my main activity.
Here is my code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.globallogic.cityguide.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/navigation_action"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />
// THIS IS MY FRAGMENTS:
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" //here is this option which cover my whole screen when i put there match_parent
            android:id="@+id/main_container"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            >
        </FrameLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/activity_outdoor_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_action"
        android:layout_gravity="start"

        >
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Give your `FrameLayout` a `weight` of `1`, and set the height to `0`.

Comment: replace LinearLayout with RelativeLayout

Comment: I don't get what gets covered that you don't want to.
Anyway the behavior of a component when its height is set to match_parent is of filling all the space available in the parent View.
If you don't want something to be overlapped and you want to control the relative position of every element you should consider using a RelativeLayout together with layout_above and layout_below, but again, your question is not clear enough for us to answer it properly.

Comment: i have app for location, in my main activity is map (google API) and i have a menu, FragmentLayout (in my main activity XML) is wrap_content (height), when i click on Settings, FragmentLayout is shows but its not cover the whole screen just a part and under settings i see map (which not should be there). When i set up match_parent for my FragmentLaout then i dont see the map in from my main activity.
Previous answer change weight and relativeLayout didnt work...

Answer (score 0):

You are using different containers, while for this purpose you'd probably rather want to just use one main container (like your xml says) and replace the fragments in it.

This way you can set your FrameLayout to fit the whole screen and just replace the settings Fragment and the Map fragment when necessary.

So the code should be changed in your MainActivity.
Let's suppose your MainActivity already extends AppCompatActivity and we have an instance of mapFragment, then you'll want to load your Map Fragment first, something like so:

```
// Add the fragment to the 'main_container' FrameLayout
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, mapFragment).commit();
```

now when you press the settings button you will just replace the fragment:

```
SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the main_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack if you want the user to be able to navigate back
transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, settingsFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

More info: [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your layout file. And other menu option from your java file.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="342dp"
    android:layout_height="473dp" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```